# Python list append only dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have a 2 dictionaries and it contains data like this:

```py
item1 = {'data': [{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}]}

item2 = {'data': [{'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]}
```

I wanted to append only `item1['data']` and `item2['data']` into the single list, how can I append this?. My expected  list is

```
[{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}, {'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]
```

Comment: `item1['data'] + item2['data']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack the list.

```
>>> item1 = {'data': [{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}]}
>>> item2 = {'data': [{'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]}
>>>
>>> [*item1['data'], *item2['data']]
[{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}, {'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]
```

Or, you can use *`list.extend`* method.

```
>>> result = item1['data'].copy()
>>> result
[{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}]
>>> result.extend(item2['data'])
>>> result
[{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}, {'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]
```

Comment: Your second approach changes `item1` too because you do `result = item1['data']`.

Comment: Thank you.The method **list.extend** is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

2 of the multiple ways:

```
item1 = {'data': [{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}]}

item2 = {'data': [{'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]}
outlist = item1['data']+item2['data']
print (outlist)
```

OR

```
item1 = {'data': [{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}]}

item2 = {'data': [{'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]}
outlist = []
for d in item1['data']:
    outlist.append(d)
for d in item2['data']:
    outlist.append(d)
print (outlist)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}, {'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply try this:**

```
item1 = {'data': [{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}]}

item2 = {'data': [{'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]}

final = item1.get('data', '') + item2.get('data', '')

print(final)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}, {'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also done by using for loop.

```
item1 = {'data': [{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}]}
item2 = {'data': [{'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]}
for item in item2['data']:
    item1['data'].append(item)
print(item1['data'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
a=[]
item1 = {'data': [{'a': 11, 'b': 22}, {'c': 33, 'd': 44}]}
item2 = {'data': [{'e': 55, 'f': 66}, {'g': 77, 'h': 88}]}

for i in range(0,2):

    var1=item1['data'][i]
    a.append(var1)

for i in range(0, 2):
    var1 = item2['data'][i]
    a.append(var1)

print(a)
```